# How to add image slider to other parts of the homepage?

Tags: image, slider

We have an image slider on out website homepage, and we want to add the same slider to other parts. This would be good to give visitors different banners to look at. I am having trouble editing it on the magento static block.

I have made a graphical example attached so you can get an idea of what we are trying to do.

Any feedback/help would be great, I am having a lot of trouble with such a small task as I am new to web coding.

Thanks in advance,

Brandon.

[image: Our Homepage Now]

[image: With the sliders added to each banner area]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need **multiple sliders on same page**. depending on the slider extension that you are using it could be **possible or not**.

Add some backend print-screens from the silder backend options. The pages where you can add/manage/delete the slider images and the ones where you can change its settings (should be under System/Configuration)

Comment: Hi Alain, I had a look in the back end under System/Configuration but could not find anything to do with our image slider. I edit the code that is in our home page (CMS/home). I edit it from time to time to add new banners and links. See screenshots: http://i.imgur.com/6efkso8.jpg   http://i.imgur.com/9MbkYmF.jpg Thanks for the help.